# Cannot get a 2160p (4K) display to work

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, lenovo

I have a lenovo X1 carbon laptop, and an external display (Philips 288P6) attached to the DisplayPort of it. The monitor can do 3840x2160 resolution, as demonstrated by the Windows 8.1 that ships with the laptop, but when I boot into a lubuntu live system, I get presented with a paltry 1920x1080 desktop.

Preferences -> Monitor Settings does not show me any larger resolutions for the external display, so I figured I had to use xrandr and help myself.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 60
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP2 "3840x2160_60.00"
$ xrandr --verbose --output DP2 --mode "3840x2160_60.00"
screen 0: 3840x2160 1016x571 mm  96.00dpi
crtc 1: 3840x2160_60.00   60.0 +0+0 "DP2"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert
```

That error message does not tell me much, I'm afraid. And this is --verbose! In the interest of getting the most helop I can, let me add some logfile output:

Xorg.0.log: http://hastebin.com/unuvocacul.log

And then there is this at the end of dmesg|tail:

[  926.163974] drm: not enough stolen space for compressed buffer (need 33177600 more bytes), disabling. Hint: you may be able to increase stolen memory size in the BIOS to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

OMG. It looks like it was the monitor all along? I finally gave up, reinstalled Windows 8, and when that could not get the desired resolution either, I swapped the monitor for an identical model - et voila, it works! I haven't tried is with Ubuntu again, because it is getting late (I am three days into this project), but there is a good chance the stupid monitor was what cased all of this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

try to go to bios and increase the amount of ram the internal graphics can stole from your main ram.

I had similar problem with getting 4k@60hz to work with intel internal graphics and only after I update kernel to 3.17 it started to work. It still does not work as default but I have to always change refresh rate to 60hz.